# OpenVPN ping windows server

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to do some VPN connections; I've read a lot of thread and doc but no way..
The scenario:

- The OpenVPN server is in a remote docker container with ip 172.16.16.1 (255.255.255.0)
- The clients can connect to the server and ping each other.
- One client is a windows server with some shared folder. I can access this shares with the VPN ip (172.16.16.6) but not with local lan ip (192.168.1.3).

Here my configuration, after a lot of attempts:

Server.conf

```
server 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key ***.key
ca ***ca.crt
cert ***.crt
dh ***dh.pem
tls-auth ***ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
client-to-client

proto udp

port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

### Route Configurations Below
route 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "block-outside-dns"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "comp-lzo no"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Client.ovpn:

```
client
nobind
dev tun
remote-cert-tls server

remote xxx 1195 udp

<key>
...
</key>
<cert>
</cert>
<ca>
...
</ca>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
</tls-auth>
```

How I can ping the 192.168.1.3 ip from openvpn server (172.16.16.1)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is probably more appropriate on a another site because StackOverflow is mainly for programmers. Maybe in the future, you should ask this kind of question on [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Now that being said, I think that you should enable your OpenVPN server to act as a router. So that if it receives a packet for another network it has access to it forward it. There's a better explanation over at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/what-is-kernel-ip-forwarding#answer-14058)

If your OpenVPN server is running on Linux, you could try to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add (or replace) this line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```